# Display month and date only in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am facing two problems in date time picker.

I want to display date as `18th January` or `January 18,` but now it is displaying as `18-1`. Documentation on datetimepicker says `"MM"` will give textual representation of month. But I am not getting that.

Also I am getting years in date dropdown.

My code is like this:

```
$(".date").datetimepicker({
    viewMode: 'months',
    format: 'DD MM'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead to use **MM** you can use **MMM**. For more info see [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

```js
$(".date").datetimepicker({
    format: 'Do MMM'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```